# mongodb error when using boost.python

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost-python

Here's my c++ code:

```
#include<boost/python.hpp>
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

using namespace mongo;
//DBClientConnection MCONNECT;

int OGS_ext(boost::python::list& ns){

  int prod(1);
  for(int i=0;i<len(ns);++i){
    prod*=boost::python::extract<int>(ns[i]);
  }
  return prod;

}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Simulate)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("OGS_ext",OGS_ext);
}
```

And here's my Makefile:

```
Simulate.so: Simulate.o
    g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic Simulate.o -L/usr/lib -lboost_python  -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -o Simulate.so
Simulate.o: Simulate.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -c Simulate.cpp
```

Everything works fine when `DBClientConnection MCONNECT` is commented out.  When I uncomment the mongo connection line, it compiles but I get the following error in Python:

```
import Simulate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./Simulate.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN5mongo18DBClientConnectionE
```

I realize I'm returning a simple product, but I've stripped the code down to provide a minimal example.

Am I having a conflict with mongodb?

Comment: Looks like a linker error rather than a conflict.  Try moving the linker arguments (i.e. `-lmongoclient ...`) from the `Simulate.o` target, where compilation occurs, to `Simulate.so`, where linking occurs.